# metrics for algorithms

Tags: performance, complexity-theory, metrics

Can anyone provide a complete list of metrics for rating an algorithm?

For example, my list starts with:

- elegance
- readability
- computational efficiency
- space efficiency
- correctness

This list is not in order and my suspicion is that it isn't near complete. Can anyone provide a more complete list?

Comment: maybe progress and safety too? those are more specific to concurrency but I think they fit

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exhaustive list may be difficult to put in a concise answer, since some important qualities will only apply to a subset of algorithms, like "levels of security offered by an encryption system for particular key sizes".

In any case, I'm interested to see more additions people might have. Here are a few:

- optimal (mathematically proven to be the best)
- accuracy / precision (heuristics)
- any bounds on best, worst, average-case
- any pathological cases? (asymptotes for chosen bad data, or encryption systems which do poorly for particular "weak" keys)
- safety margin (encryption systems are breakable given enough time and resources)